# How to populate grid view with user inputs in windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, crystal-reports

It is an invoice for an inventory where I need to make a gridView in which user will add multiple items as rows.  There are few dropdowns and textboxes through which user will select and add one by one row.
After adding, user will generate a report and data on grid view will be printed on Crystal Report. All I want to know how do I populate gridview on runtime with user input data?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out doing it this way

```
        // Creating columns and setting it readonly
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 6;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Colour";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Colour";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Code";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Code";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Length";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Length";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Quantity";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Quantity";
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();

        //Now somewhere other in code populating them this way
        int Row = 0;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        Row = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2;
        dataGridView1[0, Row].Value = Convert.ToString(CBName.SelectedValue);
        dataGridView1[1, Row].Value = Convert.ToString(CBColour.SelectedValue);
        dataGridView1[2, Row].Value = Convert.ToString(CBCode.SelectedValue);
        dataGridView1[3, Row].Value = Convert.ToString(CBLength.SelectedValue);
        dataGridView1[4, Row].Value = Convert.ToString(txtQuantity.Text);
        dataGridView1[5, Row].Value = Convert.ToString(inven.Id);
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
```